# sql dependency Invalid object name '

Tags: c#, .net, sqldependency

I am trying to use sql dependence, and I tried with making the connection with the squery, it is a very simple code:

```
public MyListener()
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM TransferToSIP WHERE hasBeenRead = false";
            SqlDependency.Start(getConnectionString(), query);
        }
```

That is the constructor.  i call it like this:

```
new MyListener();
```

but I got this exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Invalid object name 'SELECT * FROM TransferToSIP WHERE hasBeenRead = false'.
```

There is no mistake at all in the database name or the field name.

what am i doing wrong please?

Comment: I dont think there is such thing as a value 'false'. I think what you mean is `0` (assuming a column of type `bit`).

Comment: @Caramiriel no no, i already tried `0`, the same exception

Comment: @Caramiriel yes the field is bit, but when i tried `0`, i got the same exception

Comment: Also, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224871(v=vs.110).aspx expects a queue, not a query.

Comment: @Caramiriel Ohhh, i thought it is query not queue, but how can I build that queue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying a queue name instead of a query, or even without queue.

An example can be found on the reference page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I already checked that example, but that example doesn't make an exampe about queue, they just said `queueName`

Comment: Try the overload that doesn't need a queue name if you don't need one :) It is only required if you need to split the messages (change notifications) into different queues so that they can be handled concurrently.

Comment: could you please check my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718201/why-sql-dependency-is-not-working-in-this-example

Answer (score -1):

Try this if column(hasBeenRead) datatype is bit
string query = "SELECT * FROM TransferToSIP WHERE hasBeenRead = 'false'";

Answer (score -1):

"*" is not allowed. Try a selct statement with field names and maybe a dbowner